# Very slow boot time - old Toshiba L350 and Xubuntu 18.10

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 18.10

I tried to bring an old laptop to life and installed Xubuntu 18.10.
I noticed that the boot is quite long and look up on the Internet to see what could be the reason. So I did a systemd-analyze blame

Satellite-Pro-L350:~$ systemd-analyze blame

```
1min 30.059s gpu-manager.service
1min 23.006s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     37.484s apt-daily-upgrade.service
     30.695s colord.service
     28.478s apt-daily.service
     22.688s dev-sda1.device
     16.862s networkd-dispatcher.service
     12.682s snapd.service
     12.604s udisks2.service
     12.268s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     11.220s ModemManager.service
      9.772s accounts-daemon.service
      9.061s apparmor.service
      8.684s NetworkManager.service
      7.754s systemd-resolved.service
      7.569s thermald.service
      7.517s logrotate.service
      7.232s wpa_supplicant.service
      7.211s rsyslog.service
      7.202s systemd-logind.service
      7.185s apport.service
      7.182s grub-common.service
      6.999s lm-sensors.service
```

Are there updates that I'm missing? Drivers that are not up to date? I can't imagine that this is a normal boot. If you have any advice, please let me know what I can do. I don't want to have to use another distribution...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` which tells you specifically what is slowing boot.

Comment: Can you provide more specifics about your laptop's processor, hard disk and RAM?

Comment: My Toshiba is a satellite pro l350
CPU Intel® Pentium® T2390
160 Go
2,048 (1,024 + 1,024) Mo, DDR2 RAM (667 MHz)
Intel® GMA X3100

I'll do the systemd-analyze critical-chain in a few minutes.

Comment: systemd-analyze critical-chain https://pastebin.com/yNf51NPW

I remember that I had installed Xubuntu a few years ago and it took about 30 seconds. Thank you for helping me.